# Struts2 properties file reload

Tags: java, struts2

My `struts.xml`:

```xml
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.i18n.reload" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="global" />
```

When I make any changes to my `global.properties` file, it does not show any reflection on JSP pages, all I need is to reload my properties file.

I have gone through the [instructions](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/devmode.html), but I do not understand what I am missing. Please help me solve the problem.

can anyone help me to solve this??

Comment: Possibly more than one / exist of other configuration files in classpath? (e.g. `struts.properties` [unnecessary])

Answer (score 0):

The reload happens when you send a new request to the server after the modification. Haven't you done that? I have been facing this problem just now and search Apache official guideline and fount following
When enabled, Struts 2 will reload your resource bundles on every request (meaning you can change your .properties files, save them, and see the changes reflected on the next request).
Note: this option can also be set standalone via struts.i18n.reload = true